# What type of connector is this for a 24V battery and charger and where can I get them?

Tags: batteries, connector, identification

I need to identify this connector so I could order it. I also need to find a place where I can buy them.

[image]

Comment: Asking for where to buy them will have your question closed as per site rules. I suggest you delete that bit and instead add details such as the make, model, year and purpose of the equipment.

Comment: The housing looks like a DIN connector, but the pin arrangement looks non-standard.  I suggest you find a reference for DIN connectors on the web and go shopping.  Unfortunately, connectors are easy enough to make that you often find that a manufacturer will have a proprietary one -- this is why @Transistor is asking for more details.

Comment: Those din connectors do not look compatible with each other, one has a pin spacing of 60deg, the other is not an even spacing angle. The pins are not the same size on the female connector, the ones on the male are.

Comment: @VoltageSpike, I don't believe that the pins on the male connector are all the same gauge. Perhaps I am interpreting the photo differently.

Comment: @Rommelsboy You need some pin information, such as pin pitch and connector diameter

Comment: i have seen those on printers used in retail

Comment: Ask this question at Digikey forums, this is where I go :-).

Answer (score 1):

It's this Kycon one: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/222/KPPX-365228.pdf

This series was popular with laptop chargers.

So, uh, ... Mouser.